# The meaning of ‘rush’ in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Among different meanings of ‘rush’ — such as dash, run, draught, call, demand, surge — I cannot say which one is meant in this context.

> “For many people, wildness is what we experience when we go into the
> woods, ascend a mountain, or explore a desert. Wildness, from this
> perspective, refers to the unwieldy character of the more-than-human
> world. In the woods, things happen on their own—in a manner that is
> indifferent and often resistant to human design. As the word’s
> etymology suggests, ‘wild’ things are self-willed. They operate
> according to their own unique dynamics. For Leopold and fellow
> conservationists, encountering things that refuse to move to a human
> beat is a **rush**; it enlivens life. For most others, however, it
> spells annoyance and peril.”(Excerpt From
> Is Wildness Over?
> By Paul Wapner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Leopold and fellow conservationists, encountering things that refuse to move to a human beat **gives a sudden feeling** of excitement, elatement, or pleasure; it enlivens life.

> A rush
>
> noun
> (SUDDEN FEELING)
> a sudden strong emotion or physical
> feeling:
> *The memory of who he was came back to him with a rush.
>
> I had my first cigarette for a year and felt a sudden rush (of dizziness).*

[Rush (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rush)